# Improve Efficiency Adding to Interval Set Java

Tags: java, performance, intervals

I'm currently using a SortedSet to store intervals, when I add a new interval it needs to check whether or not it overlaps with existing intervals in the set.

The code I have right now is

```
public boolean add(Interval<K> i) {
    Comparable ib = i.getB();
    Comparable ia = i.getA();   
    for(Interval m : intervals) {
        Comparable b = m.getB();
        Comparable a = m.getA();

        if (a.compareTo(ia) == 0 && b.compareTo(ib) == 0) {
            return false; // same interval already there so don't add / return false
        }           
        if (b.compareTo(ia) <= 0 && a.compareTo(ia) < 0) {
            continue; // exists before current element
        }
        if (a.compareTo(ib) >= 0 && a.compareTo(ia) > 0) {
            continue; // exists after
        } 
        return false; // interval overlaps, so don't add / return false
    }
    intervals.add(i);
    return true;

}
```

For the above code, intervals is the set containing all the intervals, getB gets the end portion of the interval and getA gets the start portion of the interval.

It works fine although I am struggling to improve the efficiency as it is taking too long to execute.

Does anyone see any areas for improvement efficiency wise? Would it be possible to do this without looping all the intervals in the set?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you'll accept that, but I just suggest that you use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Because it has all the tools that you need, built in, and as you can expect from this library, thoroughly tested: [`Range`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) and [`RangeSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html).